# If I have a before action filter, how to set properties so they are available in actions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my actions, I want to pre-load the User object and set some other properties, all BEFORE the action loads.

I know there are events where I can do this, but how will these objects that I set be made available in my controller's actions once the filter fires and execution is now at the action level?

example:

public actionresult SomeAction()
{
   string username = this.CurrentUser.username;

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public override OnActionExecuting( forgotthesignature filterContext )
{
    this.CurrentUser = whatever;
}
```

Comment: so I set the property at the controller level then.